#  How to switch between graphics on Dell Inspiron N5110?

Tags: 12.04, hybrid-graphics

I have got a Dell Inspiron N5110 running Ubuntu 12.04. It has two graphic cards, Integrated Intel graphics And Nvidia. I was wondering if there is a way to switch between graphic cards. As the Nvidia card is using a lot off battery power I want the Intel card to be the default.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running on the nvidia GPU? I think your intel GPU is running your desktop while the nvidia card is sitting down wasting power. http://superuser.com/q/392098/47108

Answer (score 1):

Is it one of their Optimus cards? That's what I have, and I use [Ironhide](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/610) to switch between cards. My laptop uses the Intel card most of the time, but when I need more power I run the application through `optirun <command>`.